# Setting selected items in a GridView

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, uwp

If I have a collection of items bound to my GridView, and each item has a property *IsSelected*, how can I make sure the state of that GridViewItem is selected?

I've tried binding the property in the ItemContainerStyle with no luck.

Am I better off using an ItemTemplateSelector you think? Maybe I'll try that while I wait for any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This has always been a pain due to the lack of support for `Value`'s binding in the `Style`'s `Setter` in **Winrt**, but there is a workaround for that, which has been adapted to **winrt** (it originally targets the same limitation in Silverlight 4 - ps: Slverlight 5 support binding in Setters-), you can check it [here](https://aventuraspuntonet.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mixing-style-setters-and-bindings-in-winrt/),

but even so, for some reason [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905072/listview-itemcontainerstyle-isselected-property-does-not-seem-to-affect-selectio) also doesn't work in **Winrt** :

```
<GridView SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <GridView .ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView .ItemContainerStyle>
```

Now unless you find a better solution, here a little hack inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994021/listviewitem-isselected-binding-works-for-wpf-but-not-for-winrt) that doesn't look so clean, but it do the trick

- Extend the GridView class

  ```
  using Windows.UI.Xaml;
  using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
  using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
  using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
  public class GridViewEx : GridView
  {
      protected override void    PrepareContainerForItemOverride(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject element, object item)
     {
         base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
         var gridItem = element as GridViewItem;
         var binding = new Binding { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source =    item, Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelected") };
         gridItem.SetBinding(SelectorItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
     }
  }
  ```
- Make sure that IsSelected property is present in your `GridView` `ItemSource` Collection

  ```
  public class Item
  {
     public String Name { get; set; }
     public bool IsSelected { get; set; }         
  }
  // ..
  public ObservableCollection<Item> ListItems
  {
      get
      {
          return _listItems;
      }

      set
      {
          if (_listItems == value)
          {
              return;
          }

          _listItems = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
      }
  }
  ```
- and you are good to go

  ```
  <local:GridViewEx SelectionMode="Multiple"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" >
         <local:GridViewEx.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </local:GridViewEx.ItemTemplate>
  </local:GridViewEx>
  ```

Comment: We have to do all these due to the lack of ancestor binding. I created a API request here (https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9333168-ancestor-binding-missing). Please upvote if interested.

Comment: There is a flaw in this that if you scroll the list, the selection disappears. Not sure why/what is happening yet.

Comment: @earthling It happens due to UI virtualization. Virtualized UI probably reuses the containers and breaks the binding.